# Content of a uitable is not being saved

Tags: matlab, user-interface, user-input, matlab-guide, matlab-uitable

I'm trying to write a GUI for several purposes, that looks like this, 
[image]
one of them is create a matrix based on user input via a uitable, so in the `untitled_OpeningFcn` it was predefined the size and enabled the cell edition

```
set(handles.uitable1,'Data',cell(2,3));
set(handles.uitable1,'ColumnEditable',true(1,3))
```

inside the `pushbutton2_Callback`, I try to read the data written in the table, store it and display in a static text field:

```
value=get(handles.uitable1,'Data');
value=str2double(value);
set(handles.text2,'String',num2str(value));
```

But when it is running the text field says `"NaN"`, so the data is not being saved.

What else it is needed?

**UPDATE**
Thanks by the aswer it does not give the expected results
When using the original code it gives the next output
[image]
and when using the suggeste mat2str I got this
[image]

Comment: Did you try [debugging this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html)? My hunch is that `value=get(handles.uitable1,'Data');` doesn't result in anything that is convertible to a number (e.g. try this: `str2double({1,2,3;4,5,6})`), and so the subsequent `str2double` fails. If `handles.uitable1.Data` already contains numbers, applting `str2double` on it would just make it `NaN` (e.g. `str2double(magic(3))`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the reason for your problem is that the line

```
value = get(handles.uitable1,'Data');
```

doesn't result in anything that is convertible to a number. 
Consider the following example:

```matlab
hF = uifigure(); % works the same way with `figure()`.
hT = uitable(hF,'Data',[1 2 3; 4 5 6]);
```

Then, consider the following:

```matlab
>> hT.Data
ans =
     1     2     3
     4     5     6

>> class(hT.Data)
ans =
    'double'

>> str2double(hT.Data)
ans =
   NaN

>> mat2str(hT.Data)
ans =
    '[1 2 3;4 5 6]'
```

In conclusion - what you need is likely [`mat2str`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2str.html).